# Angular chart has not clear its old data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js, linechart

I'm having trouble on reload chart with updated details, I'm showing graph based on user activity on daily basis, on initial load with preset values the graph is formed precisely

Here I'm using flot chart library, in that flot chart library I'm using line graph

This is initial graph

[image]

But when I use custom values instead of loading a new graph with updated values, the custom values is get appended to the right end of x-axis on the graph.

When I use the custom values, the graph looks like,

[image]

In second graph, the included data will added to its old data at right side instead of showing it in correct order

here is my code for first graph, input data in vm.allsessionReport
input data will get by programmatic

```
            vm.allSessionReport = [];
            vm.sessionData = [{
                              "color": "#7dc7df",
                              "data": vm.allSessionReport
                            }];
           vm.allSessionReport = [
            ["2017-06-30", 0],
            ["2017-07-01", 0],
            ["2017-07-02", 0],
            ["2017-07-03", 0],
            ["2017-07-04", 17],
            ["2017-07-05", 0],
            ["2017-07-06", 0],
            ["2017-07-07", 0]
            ]
            vm.sessionData = [{
                              "color": "#7dc7df",
                              "data": vm.allSessionReport
                            }];                                
            console.log('session data 2nd', vm.sessionData)                                
            vm.sessionOptions = {
                series: {
                    lines: {
                        show: true,
                        fill: 0.01
                    },
                    points: {
                        show: true,
                        radius: 4
                    }
                },
                grid: {
                    borderColor: '#eee',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    hoverable: true,
                    backgroundColor: '#fcfcfc'
                },
                tooltip: true,
                tooltipOpts: {
                    content: function (label, x, y) { return x + ' : ' + y; }
                },
                xaxis: {
                    position: ($scope.app.layout.isRTL ? 'top' : 'bottom'),
                    tickColor: '#eee',
                    mode: 'categories'
                },
                yaxis: {
                    position: ($scope.app.layout.isRTL ? 'right' : 'left'),
                    tickColor: '#eee'
                },
                shadowSize: 0
            };
```

code for my second graph, input data has changed to

```
            vm.allSessionReport = [];
            vm.sessionData = [{
                              "color": "#7dc7df",
                              "data": vm.allSessionReport
                            }];
           vm.allSessionReport = [
            ["2017-06-28", 0],
            ["2017-06-29", 0],
            ["2017-06-30", 0],
            ["2017-07-01", 0],
            ["2017-07-02", 0],
            ["2017-07-03", 0],
            ["2017-07-04", 17],
            ["2017-07-05", 0],
            ["2017-07-06", 0],
            ["2017-07-07", 0]
            ]
            vm.sessionData = [{
                              "color": "#7dc7df",
                              "data": vm.allSessionReport
                            }];                                
            console.log('session data 2nd', vm.sessionData)                                
            vm.sessionOptions = {
                series: {
                    lines: {
                        show: true,
                        fill: 0.01
                    },
                    points: {
                        show: true,
                        radius: 4
                    }
                },
                grid: {
                    borderColor: '#eee',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    hoverable: true,
                    backgroundColor: '#fcfcfc'
                },
                tooltip: true,
                tooltipOpts: {
                    content: function (label, x, y) { return x + ' : ' + y; }
                },
                xaxis: {
                    position: ($scope.app.layout.isRTL ? 'top' : 'bottom'),
                    tickColor: '#eee',
                    mode: 'categories'
                },
                yaxis: {
                    position: ($scope.app.layout.isRTL ? 'right' : 'left'),
                    tickColor: '#eee'
                },
                shadowSize: 0
            };
```

Comment: can you add some code so we can help debug it?

Comment: what graph lib are you even using ? what ui-bootstrap has to do with this question ? why are you not posting any code ?

Comment: Added the code snippet that i'm currently using